# How to add a something to a string in the first column of my csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text-processing

I have 3 columns in my csv. In the first column of my csv i want to add the number "1" at start of all the entries in the column in python.
I can`t figure out how to do that?

e.g 
Current data in column: 5678967745
I want to add a 1 at the start of it so it starts like this "15678967745."
I want to do this for all entries in the column.

Comment: excellent so whats not working? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your number to a string, add the "1" as a string, and convert the whole thing back to a number, assuming that's important.

```py
numbers_as_strings = df["numbers"].astype(str)
numbers_with_1 = "1"+numbers_as_strings
numbers_as_numeric = pd.to_numeric(numbers_with_1)
df["numbers"] = numbers_as_numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have a dataframe `df` and a column named `Datetime` and it is an `int`. To modify the value avoiding the `for loop` you can use `map` on the column. You can try:

```
df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].map(lambda x: int("1"+str(x))
```

You are first converting each value in the column as a `string` and they you concatenate `1`. At the end, the new number is converted again as an `int`.

Hope it helps.